# Query works in MySQL but not via Lumen/Laravel - Numeric value out of range: 1416

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo, eloquent

I am stumped... Quite simply, I am trying to update a geometry record in a MySQL database and for some reason, it is failing. However, when Lumen throws the `QueryException`, it shows the query that is being executed;

```
UPDATE `user_locations` SET `current_location` = ST_GeomFromText('POINT(1 1)') WHERE user_id = 1
```

The above query ***works*** when I execute it in MySQL via command line, but for some reason, it does not work via Laravel/Lumen/PDO/Eloquent (not sure which one is causing the issue).

This is the error that is thrown:

```
SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1416 Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field (SQL: update `user_locations` set `current_location` = ST_GeomFromText('POINT(1 1)') where `user_id` = 1)
```

I have tried everything that I can think of;

- Downgrading MySQL (I saw others having similar issues with Mysql 5.7)
- Dumping the query and bindings directly from Eloquent to see what is actually being sent to MySQL (see below)
- Changing the engine of the database (it is currently InnoDB)
- Removing the spatial index on the `current_location` column

What else could be causing this? It cannot be MySQL as it works via command line, so it has to be something within Laravel/Eloquent/PDO surely?

### Additional Information

- I am running MySQL 5.7 (I have also tried 5.6 and it threw exactly the same error)
- I am using Lumen but don't think this is relevant as both Laravel and Lumen use Eloquent
- I am using https://github.com/grimzy/laravel-mysql-spatial and this (I believe) is the relevant code:
- **Update** - I don't think this is relevant, but there is another `point` field on this particular table but as I am not updating that field, it should be completely ignored in the query, thus, not relevant...

***Builder extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder***

```
/**
 * Update a record in the database.
 *
 * @param   array $values
 * @return  int
 */
public function update(array $values) : int
{
    foreach ($values as $key => &$value) {
        if ($value instanceof GeometryInterface) {
            $value = $this->asWKT($value);
        }
    }

    return parent::update($values);
}

/**
 * Set the MySQL for the geometry field.
 *
 * @param   GeometryInterface $geometry
 * @return  string
 */
protected function asWKT(GeometryInterface $geometry) : string
{
    return $this->getQuery()->raw("ST_GeomFromText('" . $geometry->toWKT() . "')");
}
```

In addition, I have also tried the following:

***Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder***

```
public function update(array $values)
{
    $sql = $this->grammar->compileUpdate($this, $values);

    dd($sql, $values, $this->cleanBindings(
        $this->grammar->prepareBindingsForUpdate($this->bindings, $values)
    ));

    return $this->connection->update($sql, $this->cleanBindings(
        $this->grammar->prepareBindingsForUpdate($this->bindings, $values)
    ));
}
```

This outputs:

```
string(70) "update `user_locations` set `current_location` = ? where `user_id` = ?"
array(1) {
  ["current_location"]=>
  &string(47) "ST_GeomFromText('POINT(1 1)')"
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  &string(47) "ST_GeomFromText('POINT(1 1)')"
  [1]=>
  int(1)
}
```

Comment: I hope this might be the solution: https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-disable-mysql-strict-mode/

Comment: Thanks very much @ThomasMoors, I will give this a try

Comment: I think doing it using `DB::raw` my fix your problem, take a look at this laracast discussion : https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/saving-point-data-to-mysql

Comment: Thanks @teeyo but that is exactly the same as `$this->getQuery()->raw()`. Just to be sure, I tried it 2 secs ago and unfortunately had the same result.

Comment: @teeyo I take that back (kind of), I have found the issue and it is the most pathetic, irritating and completely ridiculous mistake from me... See here `protected function asWKT(GeometryInterface $geometry) : string`. Let me know if you can spot the issue (I will post up an answer shortly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See here:

***Illuminate\Database\Query***

```
/**
 * Create a raw database expression.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $value
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression
 */
public function raw($value)
{
    return $this->connection->raw($value);
}
```

The return of `raw` is not a `string`, it is `\Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression`. Therefore, by casting the return value of `asWkt`, to a `string`, it is forcing Eloquent to wrap it with quotes, thus throwing the error we are seeing.

Comment: I noticed that but was not quite sure it's the cause of the error, glad you had it solved :)